# desktop weird behavior re. icons not displaying properly and drag and drop hanging the UI

Tags: mount, nautilus, fstab, fuse

I am transitioning from windows to ubuntu; I run 20.10 with Gnome in a partition of my disk.
I mount the windows ntfs partition's on /home/myname

My windows desktop, where I have a lot of my stuff, is therefore accessible at
/home/myname/Users/myuser/Desktop

I configured in .config/user-dirs.dirs the desktop directory to /home/myname/Users/myuser/Desktop

Up to this point everything looks ok: all of my windows desktop's files appear within ubuntu like this.

[image: icons from my desktop]

If I change an icon, for example of folder 'Libro', by editing the folder's properties, it doesn't change on the desktop but if I open a nautilus browser to that same directory, it correctly displays the new icon.

[image]

this is the first weird behaviour

a second even worse behaviour is that, when I try to drag an icon to an app (for example a file to be attached to a thunderbird email) the mouse cursor becomes a closed hand (looks like a fist) and the computer hangs. the mouse is movable; if I close the notebook it suspends, when I reopen it, the only possibility is to enter the password in the lock screen; after the lock screen I get back to exactly the same point with the computer still hanging.

my only possibility is to abruptly power off and reboot.

I wonder if the cause of both behaviours can be an issue with permissions/file system mounting.

After some trial and error, in my /etc/fstab I entered

UUID=2E54F0D254F09E31 /media/myname ntfs rw,auto,user,fmask=111,dmask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
which works quite ok, except for the to issues above.

but if I look at mount, I obtain

/dev/sda2 on /media/myname type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,user)

Here goes the question: may it really be an issue with the mounting of the filesystem ?
any hints on how to fix it ?

any help highly appreciated...

happy 2021!

Answer (score 0):

it was not an issue related to the filesystem but to the poor handling of Desktop by 20.10
the solution was to use the extension
https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng

BTW, I like tiny icons, so I had to redefine their size editing ./home/myname/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/enum.js